# Timer to show seconds, minutes and hours in iOS Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, timer, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am working on iOS Application in Xamarin.

```
timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer1.Interval = 1000;

//Play.TouchUpInside += (sender,e)=>
//{
       timer1.Enabled = true;
       Console.WriteLine("timer started");
       timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimeEvent);
//}
```

This is what i have written in viewdidload();

```
public void OnTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    count++;
    Console.WriteLine("timer tick");
    if (count == 30)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        Console.WriteLine("timer finished");

        new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                StartTimer.Text = Convert.ToString(e.SignalTime.TimeOfDay); // this works!
            });
        })).Start();
    }

    else
    {
        //adjust the UI
        new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                StartTimer.Text = Convert.ToString(e.SignalTime.TimeOfDay); // this works!
            });
        })).Start();

        timer1.Enabled = false;
        Console.WriteLine("timer stopped");
    }
}
```

This is the event I have called when I clicked on button play. I want this method to keep running so that time get updated on the label (`starttimer.Text`) in the UI. Like Runnable Interface we use in Android, what do we have to use in iOS to keep it running?

Comment: Coming in late to this question.  Both of the answers below provided what I needed.  So I gave them each an upvote.

Answer (score 7):

Use async - much cleaner (no marshalling to get you back on the main thread again!)

```
private int _duration = 0;

public async void StartTimer() {
    _duration = 0;

    // tick every second while game is in progress
    while (_GameInProgress) {
        await Task.Delay (1000);
        _duration++;

        string s = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_duration).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        btnTime.SetTitle (s, UIControlState.Normal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//before loading the view
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    ...
    StartTimer();
}
// when view is loaded  
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    ....
    UpdateDateTime();
}

private void UpdateDateTime()
{
    var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    StartTimer.Text = dateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}

private void StartTimer()
{
    var timer = new Timer(1000);
    timer.Elapsed += (s, a) => InvokeOnMainThread(UpdateDateTime);
    timer.Start();
}
```